# How does Netgear Router show more wired connections than there are LAN ports?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, lan

There is a little NETGEAR Genie WNR2000v5 wireless router in my office that I'm trying to get more acquainted with. First, I changed the password away from *password* and second I'm trying to get an idea of who/what is connecting and using the thing. I would have expected a lot of WiFi action but here is the current *Attached Devices* status as per its web interface:

[image: NETGEAR genie WNR2000v5 Attached Devices shows 8 wired devices but there are only 4 LAN ports]

The thing that confuses me, and hence my question, is that there are only 4 LAN ports on this device and yet 8 wired connections (the bottommost one, MESSIAH, is my laptop). How can this be?

Comment: I wonder ... I just noticed it says it is operating as an ACCESS POINT. Does this mean it's not routing and that these are merely other devices in the building that happen to be blasting packets through this device on the network?

Comment: Well the 4 unknown devices are two Linksys, a D-Link, and a Belkin device. Do you have any other routers or switches connected to the LAN ports? Do you have this router in bridge mode (NAT and router features turned off)? Some routers make their WAN port act as a LAN port if you put the box into bridge mode.

Comment: You can expand the number of connected hosts simply by using switches.